# ng-bootstrap ngbDatepicker shown behing ng-template modal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

I'm building a form within a modal, shown in a ng-template tag. 
`@ng-bootstrap/bootstrap` Datepicker popup is stuck behind modal, like the picture below.

[image]

How do I push calendar popup to front?

Ng Bootstrap and Angular versions are listed below:

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2"
"@angular/core": "^5.2.11"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your `styles.css` the following line:

```
.dropdown-menu.show { 
     z-index: 1090 !important; 
}
```

Comment: Try to update the library `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"`. the problem is solved in lastest version